# Problema ao mapear servlet no web xml

Tags: java, servlet

Estou recebendo erro 500 ao tentar mapear o servlet, não sei o que pode ser, acho que é o servlet class que está errado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Servlet

```
public class addContatoServlet3 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException{
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/View/adiciona-contato.jsp");
        System.out.println("testando POST");        
        try{
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {      
        System.out.println("TESTANDO GET");
    }
}
```

Web XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>testeWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>addContatoServlet3</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>src.controllers.addContatoServlet3</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addContatoServlet3</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testando</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit:**
O Eclipse inclusive lista tudo no meu mapeamento de servlets:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Ao mapear os servlets não é nescessário informar o diretório 'src'.

Então no web.xml informe os package e nome da classe.

```
<servlet-class>controllers.addContatoServlet3</servlet-class>
```

*Uma dica classes em java deve seguir um padrão(Covenção) CamelCase onde cada palavra é iniciada em maiúsculo e unidas sem espaço.*

Comment: Oi Viktor, obrigado pela resposta, mas mesmo assim continuo com o erro "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class controllers.addContatoServlet3" :(

Comment: Olá, nesse caso tem como postar o erro por completo.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta asim :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>addContatoServlet3</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.addContatoServlet3</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addContatoServlet3</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testando</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Pode usar a sim também além de não precisarmos mais fazer a declaração das suas **Servlets** em **XML**.

```
@WebServlet(value="/testando", name="addContatoServlet3")
public class addContatoServlet3 extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException{
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/View/adiciona-contato.jsp");
        System.out.println("testando POST");        
        try{
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {      
        System.out.println("TESTANDO GET");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi, Obrigado pela resposta! Mudei o web xml mas continuo com o erro "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class controllers.addContatoServlet3" , infelizmente eu tenho a necessidade de mapear meus servlets pelo web xml por demanda interna, não posso usar notation.

Comment: trocar o  protected  por public doGet e doPOST !! e testa..acho que é isso!!

Comment: Obrigado novamente, tentei aqui, mas não deu certo

Comment: Deu erro novamente? vc tem esse projeto no github ?

Comment: Eu repliquei o exato mesmo servlet, mesmo jsp, mesmo web xml em outro projeto e funcionou... como o projeto ainda é pequeno não vai me impactar muito, mas que estranho... fico imaginando se pode ser algo que "desconfigurou" no tomcat

Comment: tinha que ver o projeto..